# How to keep track of last added element of Linked List using static pointer to Node?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, data-structures, static-variables

```cpp
class Node{
    public:
        int info;
        Node* link;
        static int count;
        static Node* endNode;
        
        Node(){
            this->info = 0;
            this->link = NULL;
            if(count==0) endNode = this;
            else count++;
            
        }
    
        void insert(int x){
            Node *p = new Node;
            p->info = x;
            p->link = NULL;

            endNode->link = p;
            endNode = p;    
            
            
        }
```

Comment: Using a `static` variable for this is not a correct approach. It will make it impossible to create multiple lists. There should be a class `LinkedList` or such which contains the pointer as normal member. (The same applies to `count`.)

Comment: You are conflating the linked list's links with the linked list itself. This will make your life much more difficult. Separate the responsibilities. No variable, function, or class should do more than the minimum necessary to get its one job done efficiently.

Comment: Using `static` means that all nodes will have the same `endNode` and `count` members.  Is this intentional?  This applies to all of your different linked lists too.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` syntax.  It is only used to when the method's parameter name is the same as the member name.  The `this->` syntax can be avoiding by using different coding style for members, for example, prepending member names with "m_" or appending members with "_".

Answer (score 2):

The classic approach is to have the count and end pointer in the Linked List class:

```
class Linked_List
{
    int node_count;
    Node * p_head;
    Node * p_tail;
};
```

The `p_tail` member points to `nullptr` or the last (ending) node.

Moving the `count` member to a `Linked_List` class allows for different linked lists to have different node quantities.